# How can I request mobile version of a site locally (from my extension)?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm developing an extension for Firefox and I wonder: Is there any way to see request mobile version of a site? In Firefox for Android there is a menu item that let's you request the "desktop version" of a webpage. How can I do the reverse?

Thanks a lot,
G.

Comment: Hi cbayram! Why did not you answer in an answer instead of a comment? This can be a possible solution :P

Comment: fair enough! Was a brainstorm rather than a comprehensive answer, but if it helps youthat's what matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on each site's implementation of "mobile" detection. Some will be responsive based screen size (using media queries client-side) where you can minimize your window size to test. Others will read the User Agent Header on the HTTP request coming into the server and serve up the mobile version. User Agent can be spoofed. [Google for a Search Engine Spoofer Firefox Plug-in](https://www.google.com/search?q=Firefox+user+agent+spoofer&oq=Firefox+user+agent+spoofer) and change it to a say IPhone User Agent for example